# \MakeUppercase does not work with Ukrainian in Xelatex

Tags: xetex, babel, capitalization, ukrainian

`\MakeUppercase` does not work only with `Ukrainian` in `XeLaTeX`

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}
    \usepackage{xecyr}
    \usepackage{textcase}
    \setmainfont[
      Ligatures=TeX,
      Extension=.otf,
      BoldFont=cmunbx,
      ItalicFont=cmunti,
      BoldItalicFont=cmunbi,
    ]{cmunrm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\selectlanguage{english}
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\\
\selectlanguage{russian}
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\\
\selectlanguage{ukrainian}
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\\
\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\\
\end{document}
```

When I adding in preamble

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
```

`\MakeUppercase` starts.
Should I use `fontenc` with `XeLaTeX`? Or it is a bug of `babel` or something else?

Comment: The `babel` module for Russian has been updated for use with XeTeX, the module for Ukrainian hasn't.

Comment: @egreg I try to update. It does not differ significantly. But, may be the author is at the Tex.SX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `babel` module for Russian has been updated for use with XeLaTeX, but the one for Ukrainian hasn't.

You're luckier with Polyglossia.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunbx,
  ItalicFont=cmunti,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunbi,
]{cmunrm}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\selectlanguage{english}
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}

\selectlanguage{russian}
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}

\selectlanguage{ukrainian}
\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}

\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptertitlename}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Case mapping for Cyrillic in “traditional” LaTeX is defined by `fontenc`. Unfortunately they are defined only if a few “known” encodings are loaded, whose list is hardcoded and does not include EU1. But they may forced with something like:

```
\usepackage[T2A,EU1]{fontenc}    % or X2,LCY..
```

The MWE seems to work, but I'm not sure this solution is general enough. And yes, with `babel` (and very likely other packages based on the LICR) you must use `fontenc`.

Comment: While this has nothing to do with XeLaTeX mentioned by OP, this worked for me with plain LaTeX: the absence of `fontenc` was the very reason why `\MakeUppercase` did not work before.